# Find row indices of empty cells in a given range

Tags: excel, vba, readxl

Is it possible to write a vba macro that determines if there are any empty cells in a given range and returns the row number of that cell?

I'm new to vba and all that I managed to write after searching the internet was something that takes a range and colors every emty cell in it red:

```
Sub EmptyRed()
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
    For Each cell In Selection
        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

The macro does basically what I want, but instead of coloring the empty cell red I would like to know the row index of the empty cell.

A little background info: I have a very large file (about 80 000 rows) that contains many merged cells. I want to import it into R with readxl. Readxl splits merged cells, puts the value in the first split cell and NA into all others. But a completely empty cell would also be assigned NA, so I thought the best thing would be to find out which cells are empty with Excel, so that I know which NA indicate a merged cell or an empty cell. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem are very welcome, thanks!

Edit: To clarify: Ideally, I want to unmerge all cells in my document and fill each split cell with the content of the previously merged cell. But I found macros on the web that are supposed to do exactly that, but they didn't work on my file, so I thought I could just determine blank cells and then work on them in R. I usually don't work with Excel so I know very little about it, so sorry if my thought process is far too complicated.

Comment: And what output do you need? Message box?

Comment: That doesnt really matter I think, I just need to be able to copy the row numbers and paste them somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you state in your title:

```
If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Debug.Print cell.Row
```

But there are also Excel methods to determine merged cells and act on them.  So And I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with the information.

**EDIT**

Adding on what you say you want to do with the results, perhaps this VBA code might help:

```
Option Explicit
Sub EmptyRed()
    Dim myMergedRange As Range, myCell As Range, myMergedCell As Range
    Dim rngProcess As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set rngProcess = Range("A1:B10")
    For Each myCell In rngProcess
        If myCell.MergeCells = True Then
            Set myMergedRange = myCell.MergeArea
            With myMergedRange
                .MergeCells = False
                .Value = myCell(1, 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next myCell

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End sub
```

Note that I explicitly declare all variables, and I hard coded the range to check.  There are various ways of declaring the range to be checked; using 'Selection' is usually rarely preferred.

Comment: Thanks! Ideally, I want to unmerge all cells in my document and fill each split cell with the content of the previously merged cell. But I found macros in the internet that are supposed to do exactly that, but they didn't work on my file, so I thought I could just determine blank cells and then work on them in R. I usually don't work with Excel so I know very little about it.

Comment: @Florian See my Edit

Comment: Thank you very much, on a sample file the macro works exactly how I imagined it, now I'll try my large file. Hard Coding the range is fine, I only need to run the macro on a few columns so I can specify the range.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else:  From the opposite end of the spectrum, you can use [`Range.MergeCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergecells) or [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) to determine if a Cell is part of a Merged Area.  But, I digress...

You can use `Cell.Row` to get the row number.  How you return or display that is up to you - could be a Message Box, a delimited string, or an array, or even a multi-area range.

A `Sub` cannot return anything once called, so you may want a `Function` instead, e.g. `Public Function EmptyRed() As String`

(Also, I would recommend you get in the habit of explicitly declaring **all** of your variables, and perhaps using `Option Explicit` too, before you run into a typo-based error.  Just add `Dim cell As Range` at the top of the sub for now)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FF()
    Dim r, wksOutput As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, rngArea As Range
    With Selection
        .UnMerge
        '// Get only blank cells
        Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        '// Make blank cells red
        rng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End With
    '// Create output worksheet
    Set wksOutput = Sheets.Add()
    With wksOutput
        For Each rngArea In rng.Areas
            For Each cell In rngArea
                r = r + 1
                '// Write down the row of blank cell
                .Cells(r, 1) = cell.Row
            Next
        Next
        '// Remove duplicates
        .Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Array(1), xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the macro also counts split merged cells as empty, which is what I want to avoid. Sorry if my formulation was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways:

```
Sub EmptyRed()

Dim rgn,targetrgn as range 
Dim ads as string ‘ return rgn address
Set targetrgn= ‘ your selection
For Each rgn In Targetrgn
    If IsEmpty(rgn.Value) Then 
        ‘1. Use address function, and from there you can stripe out the column and row
        Ads=application.worksheetfunction.addres(cell,1)’ the second input control the address format, w/o $
        ‘2. Range.row & range.column
       Ads=“row:” & rgn.row & “, col: “ & rgn.column

    End if
Next rgn
```

End Sub

Ps: I edited the code on my phone and will debug further when I have a computer. And I am just more used to use “range” rather than “cell”.

Answer (score 0):

> <sub>To clarify: Ideally, I want to unmerge all cells in my document and fill each split cell with the content of the previously merged cell.</sub>

- Cycle through all cells in the worksheet's UsedRange
- If merged, unmerge and fill the unmerged area with the value from the formerly merged area.
- If not merged but blank, collect for address output.

  ```
  Sub fillMerged()

      Dim r As Range, br As Range, mr As Range

      For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
          If r.Address <> r.MergeArea.Address Then
              'merged cells - unmerge and set value to all
              Set mr = r.MergeArea
              r.UnMerge
              mr.Value = mr.Cells(1).Value
          ElseIf IsEmpty(r) Then
              'unmerged blank cell
              If br Is Nothing Then
                  Set br = r
              Else
                  Set br = Union(br, r)
              End If
          End If
      Next r

      Debug.Print "blank cells: " & br.Address(0, 0)

  End Sub
  ```